# Grafana plugin activation

Tags: monitoring, grafana, zabbix

Is there any way to enable a grafana plugin within its configuration files?

I am using grafana v5 or v4

It looks like you have to login and then click then enable button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem running docker with a volume that would map the default sqlite db for grafana in /var/lib/grafana/grafana.db
this would keep any configuration, dashboard, datasource firstly set up in the web interface

Comment: That's a nice solution. I've looked up the official [repo](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker) for the grafana docker image, the plugin installation seems to be supported with '-e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-clock-panel,grafana-simple-json-datasource" '. Maybe it's possible to extend run.sh to manage datastsore configuration via api

Comment: FYI I've forked the repo and partially implemented what you need, with plugin autoenable and datasource import from json: "docker run -e GF_DATASOURCES="$( cat ds.json  )" -e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app" -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana:master"). I'll do a pull request soon, then I'll try to add dashboard importing also.

Comment: I've done the pull request, feel free to check if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Zabbix Plugin for Grafana](https://grafana.com/plugins/alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app).

You need to install and enable the plugin, then configure the Zabbix datasource:

- URL: http://yourserver/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php
- access: proxy or direct, depends on the reachability of Zabbix and grafana servers
- username: use a dedicated one, with the required read permissions

And you're ready to create dashboards by referencing groups, applications, hosts and items.

[Here](http://docs.grafana-zabbix.org/guides/gettingstarted/) you can find the getting starded guide, it's quite complete.
The regexp & templating features are really powerful, I advise to read it carefully.

Comment: thanks but I meant to enable the plugin programmatically.  I know how to enable and configure it throught the web interface. Or even how to enable with plugins with the grafana api. But cannot seem to find the right configuration parameter to do this. This would very helpful in a docker environment to be able to restart the containers without reconfiguring anything.